# Trying to add Domain Global group to a remote machine local group in the domain with powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, perl-module

I am currently trying to add domain global group (Desktopgr) to my local group (Localgr).
Let me precise this in more details:
I had a machine 2008 server (LDAPCLIENT, ip 10.112.252.222) in a domain (GermanTool.com).
I have a AD (Active directory) server (Vcenter, ip 10.112.252.218).
GermanTool.com is the only domain in the AD server.
The domain has many global group, one of it is 'Desktopgr'.
This group cntains user who can log in to any server in the domain through RDP.

From GUI server management tool, I can add the Domain Global group (Desktopgr) to a member of computer local group (Localgr)
I have already login to the LDAPCLIENT machine as a domain user 'GermanTool\rohit' and password '%%%%%'.

I have removed that group from Localgr. Now I try to write a Powershell script to work the same thing.
I am already logged in as a domain user to the LADPCLIENT machine and both the machines can be pinged from either side and both are in same domain.

I run the script I wrote but getting error as:

> Exception calling "Add" with "1" argument(s): "Access is denied.
>
> At C:\script\a.ps1:44 char:20
>
> - $LocalGroup.Add <<<< ($DomainGroup.Path)
> - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseAdapterMethodInvokeTI

The Script is given bellow:

```
#######################################################################

#
# File: Add2LocalGr.ps1
# Purpose: Example of adding a Domain group to a Local group
# Author: Rohit Basu
# Date: 12/05/2013



# Get List of Servers from Flat TXT file`Servers.txt`
$Servers = Get-Content Servers.txt


#GermanTool
#"LDAP://ldap.company.com:389/$($dn)"
#$credn = New-Object -TypeNam System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://10.112.252.218:389/GermanTool","rohit","%%%%%")

#Initaliaze the Domain Group Object
$DomainGroup = [ADSI]"WinNT://10.112.252.218/Desktopgr,Group"
#$DomainGroup = "$credn/Globalgroup,Group"

#Name the LogFile and Initialize it
$LogFile = ".\Logs\ServerLog.txt"
New-Item $LogFile -type file -force

ForEach ($Server in $Servers) #Loop through each server
{
$Server
$Server>>$LogFile


#Get Local Group object
$LocalGroup = [ADSI]"WinNT://$Server/Localgr,Group"

"Hi This is to see Localgroup">>$LogFile
$LocalGroup.Path>>$LogFile
"Hi This is to see Globalgroup">>$LogFile 
$DomainGroup.Path>>$LogFile


#Assign DomainGroup to LocalGroup
$LocalGroup.Add($DomainGroup.Path)

#Determine if command was successful
If (!$?) #Add failed
{
    $Server + " fail: " + $Error[0]>>$LogFile
    "">>$LogFile
}
 Else #Add succeeded
 {
    $Server + " success">>$LogFile
    "">>$LogFile
    $Server + " success"
 }
}
#####################################################
```

The Servers.txt file contains one Ip: 10.112.252.222

Comment: I'd recommend doing this with a group policy rather than a script.

Comment: The user who execute the script is not allowed to modify le local group on the machine. Perhaps you just need to run your script as administator.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, The requirement is for automation, so script.

Comment: Group policies are just a different kind of automation, and one that grants better control in most domain scenarios. What are your business requirements, i.e. why do you believe you need to do this with a script?

Comment: As for admin privileges: if UAC is enabled you need to explicitly run the script "as administrator".

Comment: Thanks JPBlanc. I did misinterpret you answer. yes need to loggin as local administrator to run this script. Mistake I was doing was loggin from a domain user who has domain admin & Administrators group right.